# Create derived classes with parameterized constructors using factory method with type parameter

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

I have an abstract base class and a derived class. Let us call them `Base` and `Derived`.

`Base` has the constructor:

```
public Base(int number)
{
    // do something with number
}
```

and the `Derived` class will *always* have the constructor ([even though this cannot be ensured through an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619856/interface-defining-a-constructor-signature), this is nevertheless the case in my program):

```
public Derived(int number) : base(number)
{
    // do some other stuff
}
```

Now, I would like a factory method to create objects derived from `Base`, which should be called like this:

```
Base.Create<Derived>(someNumber);
```

But I do not know how to implement this method in a correct fashion. I think the most elegant solution would be to do something like this:

```
public static T Create<T>(int number) where T : Base, new(int)
{
    return new T(number);
}
```

But it seems that [C# does not support the parameterized constructor constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408044/specifying-constructor-constraint-for-generic-parameter) `new(int)`, only the parameterless one. This solution would have been so clear and it expresses exactly what I want. Oh well..

Instead, I could basically switch on the type parameter and create and instance of the correct type like this:

```
public static Base Create<T>(int number) where T : Base, new(int)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Derived))
    {
        return new Derived(number);
    }
    // and so on for all other derived types
}
```

But this requires me to update the method every single time I make a new derived class, which is unfortunate. Besides, `typeof(T) == typeof(Derived)` seems way too hackish. Also, with this approach it seems the return type of the factory method will have to be `Base` instead of `T`, which is also unfortunate. I could just as easily resort to using enums instead of a type parameter in that case.

I wonder if there is a better way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an Activator to create an instance:

```
public static T Create<T>(int number) where T : Base
{
    return (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (T), number);
}
```

In this case you will not need to update the method if you create a new derived class. This assumes that you always have a constructor which takes a single integer parameter. If such constructor does not exist you will get a runtime exception.